# Programmatically scrolling UIScrollView then over-riding with manual scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview, overriding

I want a scroll view to automatically scroll when the user first loads the screen... so I'm using this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(float)1.25f
                     animations:^{
                         myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(2000, 800);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

So the code works great and the UIScrollView simulates a "scroll" (animation) to the CGPoint I want, but while it's scrolling if the user wants to manually put their finger on it and start scrolling or just stop it, the user can't over-ride this animation until after it's completed.

Anyone have any ideas of a better method to animate it with over-ride capabilities, and when to call said over-ride capabilities (I'm assuming this will involve touchesBegan on scrollView's view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to your animation options:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.25f delay:0.0f options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
                     _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 800);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

And cancel the animation on the UIScrollView `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //Storing current offset
    CALayer *currentLayer = _scrollView.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGPoint scrollBoundsOrigin = currentLayer.bounds.origin;

    //Cancelling animations
    [_scrollView.layer removeAllAnimations];

    //Restore offset
    _scrollView.contentOffset = scrollBoundsOrigin;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thankyou so much! Worked like a charm :)